# Ubuntu: How to get the name of the active keyboard using C++ gtk or xkb

Tags: c++, ubuntu, keyboard, gdk

I am working with code( C++, ubuntu, gdk, xkb) where I use a german Keyboard which is on the top of the list in settings->Keyboard->input sources .

In my program I can access the keycode, keyval, keymaps used for the language which is on top of that list; (if I change the language I get different results - which is fine and of course should work this way)

Now in my C++ program I want to access the *name* of the active keyboard like "german" or "french". **How can I access the name of the active keyboard using c++ gdk or xkb**

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu, you can read it from /etc/default/keyboard:

```
$ cat /etc/default/keyboard
XKBLAYOUT="us"
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

Or use the setxkbmap command:

```
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,us
variant:    ,
```